# How to show two regression trend lines in one chart using excel 365

Tags: excel, linear-regression, trendline

I want to plot two trend lines, one from 2-3 cm and the other from 3-4 centimeter like the attached picture. How can I do it using Excel 365?

[image: Sample]

My output is coming like this
[image: My output]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without the need to split your dataset.

[image]

The chart is a XY scatterplot, with 7 series (Vol-1, Vol-2, Vol-3, Vol-4, Vol-5, Trend1, and Trend2)

The Trend1 series is a bit weird, but basically in the Series X Values box, you select the Dist column (A2:A4 only) 5 times separated by a comma:

```
=('Temp Sheet'!$A$2:$A$4,'Temp Sheet'!$A$2:$A$4,'Temp Sheet'!$A$2:$A$4,'Temp Sheet'!$A$2:$A$4,'Temp Sheet'!$A$2:$A$4)
```

Then in the Series y-value box, you select the appropriate rows in each of the Vol columns:

```
=('Temp Sheet'!$B$2:$B$4,'Temp Sheet'!$C$2:$C$4,'Temp Sheet'!$D$2:$D$4,'Temp Sheet'!$E$2:$E$4,'Temp Sheet'!$F$2:$F$4)
```

So Trend1 looks like this:

[image]

Repeat the same thing for Trend2, but with rows 4 through 6.

Next, add a trend line for Trend1 and Trend2.

[image]

Finally, remove the markers for Trend1 and Trend2 so the only datapoints visible are Vol1 through Vol5.

From there you may choose to add axis titles, set axis limits, etc.

Comment: You may also find this article useful: https://peltiertech.com/trendline-for-multiple-series/

Answer (score 0):

Split your data into two series (2-3 and 3-4), then add a trendline to each series.

Comment: A little more explanation will help a noob like me. Does it require the regression data at all or I can draw it from simple distance vs temperature data for this graph?

Comment: Make an XY chart with two data series: the data with x values from 2 to 3, and the data with x values from 3 to 4 (with the last and first data points in both series, so that the lines overlap). Then right-click on each series and select 'Add trendline' to add the regression line. In the trendline options, you can choose to display the equation and R-squared.

Comment: For each x value, there are 5 y values, How will I manage that? will the first column automatically be taken as x values? Sorry, if I am asking too basic.

Comment: Make each set of y values a separate series. They can share the x values. e.g. have the x values 2 to 3 in column A, and the y values in columns B to F. Then have the x values 3 to 4 in column H and the corresponding y values in columns I to M.

Comment: I have shared the data and what I have tried following your instructions in OP. However, could not make it work as intended. Kindly guide me step wise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help? Still stuck in the same place plus the number of legends became double with same name due to two series.